# scheduler backup command history every restart

Tags: linux, cron, reboot

how to make scheduler backup command history every restart ?
i try with
`crontab -e`
`@reboot history > backup.txt`

and I reboot my pc there is a file backup.txt in directory but the file is empty, there are no results of the command history

Answer (score 2):

First thanks for answer
Before see answer i found the solution

`crontab -e`
`@reboot cp /home/username/.bash_history /home/username/History_Command.txt`

And it works

Comment: I advise perform this checking before replace the history file to avoid backup the truncated history file if something went wrong. (adjust 10000 to your current total lines, and also <username> and pls_check_bash_history path):

`SHELL=/bin/bash`
`@reboot if [[ $(wc -l </home/<username>/.bash_history) -ge 10000 ]]; then cp /home/<username>/.bash_history /home/<username>/.bash_history_reboot_bk; else echo $(wc -l </home/<username>/.bash_history) > /home/<username>/Downloads/pls_check_bash_history; fi`

Comment: Worth adding `--backup` option to the previous comment script to avoid truncated history issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bash's `history` doesn't work that way. Read [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145250/where-is-bashs-history-stored) for more information.

A direct quote from the link above:

> Bash maintains the list of commands internally in memory while it's
>   running.

Since Bash is not running after a reboot, you get no output.

Furthermore, `cron` does not use the same `PATH` as your Bash shell does. More on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264607/bash-script-not-executing-from-crontab#264645).

Answer (score 0):

Since the history is just a file, you could simply copy it:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 
@reboot cp $HOME/.bash_history $HOME/backup.txt 2>&1
```