# Can I do the equivalent of tail -f for bash history?

Tags: bash, centos, command-history

I'd like to be able to watch the `history` of a user, but in real time. My first thought was to use `tail -f` to track whatever file updates the history. Is this possible? Or, is there a better alternative to see real-time commands?

The specific scenario I'm in is where I and another engineer are sudo'd to the same user -- as this user, I'd like to see commands executed by this user.

Comment: Not easy unless the other user is cooperating (which they probably will in your case).

Answer (score 5):

The history on `~/.bash_history` gets written on log out, not before. If you want this, it has already been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145250/where-is-bashs-history-stored):

> If you want to make sure that they're always written immediately, you can put that command into your `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable:
>
> `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`

After this you can make a `tail -f $HISTFILE` or `tail -f ~/.bash_history`, if the `$HISTFILE` environment variable is not set (the default location is `~/.bash_history`, but it might change) and will see the commands getting added to the history file in real time.

Comment: This assumes that `HISTFILE` is unset or set to that particular filename.  Using `$HISTFILE` would be better (testing whether it's set first, or setting it).

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should cover most cases

Answer (score 0):

You could use either [psacct](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/accounting.html)(somewhat dated) or [auditd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing)(much more flexible) to monitor what processes a user runs.  Auditd can be set up right away and it'll start logging user executions, although it's a complicated system.