# Access last command of history within a function

Tags: bash, command-history, function

I'm trying to create a function that will echo the previous to last command from the current terminal. This is the expected output (here I call the desired function `f`):

```
$ history 1
history 1
$ f
history 1
```

---

Side question: Where does `history(1)` saves the current terminal's history. I know that when the terminal session ends history is typically saved in `$HISTFILE` (which is set to `~/.bash_history` in my case). But I'd like to know where `history(1)` keeps the history of the currently running terminal.

Comment: Not a function (so not an answer) but `!!:p` prints the last command without executing it.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145254/40484

Comment: The command you want is ``fc -ln -1`` (that’s ``FC -LN -(one)``, which works fine in a function.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I updated my answer using *fc*  which  simplifies the function by a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
f()(echo $(history 2 | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2-))
```

or using `fc` as suggested by G-Man:

```
f()(fc -ln -1)
```

test:

```
$ echo 123*
123*
$ f
echo 123*
```